# How restore back up email files in qmail

Tags: linux, backup, restore, email, cdp

I have problem with restoring some old backup mail files in a mail server that uses `qmail`. The problem is, when I copy a new email file to the `/cur` directory, the number of emails in front of inbox increases, but when I click on the inbox, I don't see the newly copied email. I can only see the old emails. I also deleted `maildirsize` and `courierimapuiddb` files and they where automatically created again, but it didn't help and I cannot still see the email in my inbox. Is there something I am missing? How can I restore the backed up email files? Please note that when I copy the email files in `/.sent-mail/cur` directory, they are all displayed in my sent box, but that doesn't happen for inbox files in `/cur` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this question:
[How restore qmail backup files](https://serverfault.com/questions/122325/how-restore-qmail-backup-files)